# IDirect3DDevice9 Release deadlock

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d9

What could cause this? I use direct3d9 from a dll on windows 8. No calls originate from DllMain.

All calls to the api and winapi for my window are done from the same thread. All ressources associated with the device were freed.

Comment: A few questions:
How do you detect that it really is the deadlock?
Do you release device inside window message handler?
Do you use D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED flag?
Did you try debug version of D3D runtime?
Do you use software that intercepts D3D calls, like Fraps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else gets this not really helpful behaviour out of his program:

This issue was caused by the window of the device being not properly destroyed.